# grep a pattern in list of gzip files recursively

Tags: bash, unix, command-line, grep

I am using the following command on command line for getting the pattern matched lines.

```
find . -name "*.gz"|xargs gzcat|grep -e "pattern1" -e "pattern2"
```

i need now to find only the file names where the pattern is present.
how can i do it on command line?

`grel -l` has no use since i am using `xargs gzcat` before `grep`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i in $(find . -name "*.gz"); do gzcat $i|grep -qe "n1" -e "n2" && echo $i; done
```

Comment: just missed the thought.if i had got it,i would have written a similar command.

Comment: Works nicely on a system without zgrep, where I don't have root permission. Thank you. On some system you may have to use gcat instead of gzcat.

Answer (score 5):

Check if you have zgrep available. And then, if yes:

```
find . -name '*.gz' -exec zgrep -l -e ".." -e ".." {} +
```

If you don't have it - well, just copy it from some machine that has it (all linuxes I use have it by default) - it's a simple bash script.

Answer (score 2):

#### [`ripgrep`](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep)

Use `ripgrep`, for example, it's very efficient, especially for large files:

```
rg -z -e "pattern1" -e "pattern2" *.gz
```

or:

```
rg -z "pattern1|pattern2" .
```

or:

```
rg -zf pattern.file .
```

<sup>Where `pattern.file` is a file containing all your patterns separated by a new line character.</sup>

> `-z`/`--search-zip` Search in compressed files (such as `gz`, `bz2`, `xz`, and `lzma`).

Answer (score 1):

Untested; does everything inside find so if you have loads of gz files you wont have performance problems as runs each gzcat/grep as soon as it finds files nothing is piped out:

```
find . -iname '*.gz' -exec bash -c 'gzcat $1 | grep -q -e "pattern1" -e "pattern2" && echo $1' {} {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

In bash, I'd do something like this (untested):

```
find . -name '*.gz' | while read f ; do gzcat $f | grep -q -e "pattern1" -e "pattern2" && echo $f ; done
```

Answer (score 0):

#### `grep`/`zgrep`/`zegrep`

Use `zgrep` or `zegrep` to look for pattern in compressed files using their uncompressed contents (both GNU/Linux and BSD/Unix).

On Unix, you can also use `grep` (which is [BSD version](https://wiki.freebsd.org/BSDgrep)) with `-Z`, including `-z` on macOS.

Few examples:

```
zgrep -E -r "pattern1|pattern2|pattern3" .
zegrep "pattern1|pattern2|pattern3" **/*.gz
grep -z -e "pattern1" -e "pattern2" *.gz # BSD/Unix only.
```

<sup>Note: When you've [globbing option enabled](https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/globstar-new-bash-globbing-option), `**` checks the files recursively, otherwise use `-r`.</sup>

> `-R`/`-r`/`--recursive` Recursively search subdirectories listed.
>
> `-E`/`--extended-regexp` Interpret pattern as an extended regular expression (like `egrep`).
>
> `-Z` ([BSD](https://man.openbsd.org/grep)), `-z`/`--decompress` ([BSD/macOS](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/grep.1.html)) Force grep to behave as `zgrep`.