# Check if a file contains a multi-line string in bash

Tags: string, bash, macos, grep, bsd

### Background

I am writing a function to append to a file in my `$HOME` directory called `.bash.local`.

➡️ `.bash.local` is sourced via `.bash_profile`.

However, I want to conditionally append to `.bash.local` **if and only if** the file **does not** already contain the contents of `$BASH_CONFIGS`.

### Things to Keep in Mind

My operating system of choice is `MacOS Mojave`, thus certain versions of command line applications will be different (e.g. `grep` on a Mac is `BSD grep` and not `GNU grep`).

### ⚠️ append_to_bash_local()

```
append_to_bash_local() {
    local LOCAL_BASH_CONFIG_FILE="$HOME"/.bash.local

    declare -r BASH_CONFIGS="
# TOOL_NAME - TOOL_DESCRIPTION.
# Add tool configurations here
"

    # - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

    # If needed, add the necessary configs in the
    # local shell configuration file.

    if ! grep "^$BASH_CONFIGS" < "$LOCAL_BASH_CONFIG_FILE" &> /dev/null; then
        # this block never runs, even if the contents of $BASH_CONFIG
        # are NOT present in $HOME/.bash.local
    fi

}
```

Comment: How to do the reverse. Delete the string from bash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a little help from [@kamil-cuk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9072753/kamil-cuk), I was able to create a more improved version of `append_to_bash_local()`.

⚠️ Please note that because I am on `MacOS Mojave` & have both `BSD-grep` & `BSD-sed` installed by default & neither `GNU-grep` nor `GNU-sed` installed, I was forced to find a different solution for *truncating new-line characters with the ASCII NUL character*.  Thankfully, [@kamil-cuk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9072753/kamil-cuk) had a *hacky* solution using `tr`.

Below is the improved version of `append_to_bash_local()`.

### ⚠️ `append_to_bash_local()`

1. First, check if the file does not exist with `[ ! -e "$LOCAL_BASH_CONFIG_FILE" ]`.
2. Second, use `-q` with `grep` to make it silent.

   - ➡️ Make sure to put a `!` (not) in the front of `grep -q` to make sure the status of the output is inverted since we are checking if the file *does not contain* the contents of `$BASH_CONFIGS`.
3. Lastly, use `"$(<<<"$BASH_CONFIGS" tr '\n' '\01')" < <(less "$LOCAL_BASH_CONFIG_FILE" | tr '\n' '\01')` in order to *truncate new-line characters with the ASCII NUL character* in both `$BASH_CONFIGS` & `$LOCAL_BASH_CONFIG_FILE`.

   ```
   append_to_bash_local() {

       local LOCAL_BASH_CONFIG_FILE="$HOME"/.bash.local

       declare -r BASH_CONFIGS="
       # TOOL_NAME - TOOL_DESCRIPTION.
       # Add tool configurations here
       "

       # - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

       # If needed, add the necessary configs in the
       # local shell configuration file.

       if [ ! -e "$LOCAL_BASH_CONFIG_FILE" ] || ! grep -q "$(<<<"$BASH_CONFIGS" tr '\n' '\01')" < <(less "$LOCAL_BASH_CONFIG_FILE" | tr '\n' '\01'); then
           printf '%s\n' "$BASH_CONFIGS" >> "$LOCAL_BASH_CONFIG_FILE"
       fi

   }
   ```

Answer (score 3):

You are close. Anyway, small fixes:

- use zero separated `grep -Z` to match patterns with newlines. If you think of it, it is a bit of hacky, but works every time.
- use `-q` to grep to make it silent.
- and don't input the file to stdin to grep, just tell grep the filename.
- check if a file does exists

```
append_to_bash_local() {
     local LOCAL_BASH_CONFIG_FILE="$HOME"/.bash.local
     declare -r BASH_CONFIGS="
# TOOL_NAME - TOOL_DESCRIPTION.
# Add tool configurations here
"

if [[ "$(uname)" == "Linux" ]]; then
    if
           # if a file does not exists
           [ ! -e "$LOCAL_BASH_CONFIG_FILE" ] ||
           # if it doesn't have the content of BASH_CONFIGS
           ! grep -q -z "$BASH_CONFIGS" "$LOCAL_BASH_CONFIG_FILE"; then
        echo appending
        printf '%s\n' "$BASH_CONFIGS" >> "$LOCAL_BASH_CONFIG_FILE"
    else
        echo not appending
    fi

elif [[ "$(uname)" == "Darwin" ]]; then
    if 
            [ ! -e "$LOCAL_BASH_CONFIG_FILE" ] || 
            ! grep -q "$(<<<"$BASH_CONFIGS" tr '\n' '\01')" < <(
                less "$LOCAL_BASH_CONFIG_FILE" | tr '\n' '\01'
            ); then
        echo appending
        printf '%s\n' "$BASH_CONFIGS" >> "$LOCAL_BASH_CONFIG_FILE"
    else
       echo not appending
    fi
fi

}
```

Comment: Okay, so after some initial testing, the `grep -z` command returns `grep: invalid option -- z`. However, according to `grep`'s man page, `-z` & `-Z` **do** exist and have the following behavior: `Force grep to behave as zgrep`. Moreover, however, when adding `zgrep -q` or `grep -q -Z` instead of `grep -q -z` in your code block above, it still returns `not appending` even if the contents of `$BASH_CONFIGS` **do not** exist within `$HOME/.bash.local`. I am on a Mac running MacOS Mojave & the results after running `grep -V` is: `grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD`. Any thoughts?

Comment: According [How do I grep for multiple patterns on multiple lines?](https://askubuntu.com/q/551338/552275), it appears that Linux-based OS's such as `ubuntu` may have a different `grep` version installed because the man page results for `grep -z` is different than the man page for `grep` on Mojave. As seen on the page [How do I grep for multiple patterns on multiple lines?](https://askubuntu.com/q/551338/552275): `Treat the input as a set of lines, each terminated by a zero byte (the ASCII 
      NUL character) instead of a newline.` While on Mojave: `Force grep to behave as zgrep`.

Comment: `GNU grep` is different than `BSD grep` which they both have a different set of options for `-z` or `-Z`, thus, since I'm on a Mac and am without `GNU grep` installed by default, _is there a different solution available that you know of that will work on a Mac?_ See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49805153/5290011 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/152755/5290011.

Comment: Well, then tricky, you can substitute newlines for an unreadable character in the file, then grep for the pattern `grep -q "$(<<<"$BASH_CONFIGS" tr '\n' '\01')" < <(tr '\n' '\01' "$LOCAL_BASH_CONFIG_FILE")`. You could `sed -z`, but you would need to omit the `/` character unless you program some escaping. `sed -z -n "/${BASH_CONFIGS}/p" "$LOCAL_BASH_CONFIG_FILE"`